# Why is everything a tuple in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, tuples

So I found out that any variable or constant in swift is a tuple. For example, variable x below is a tuple

```
var x = 15
```

and following statement is valid and evaluates to value of x as the first element of tuple

```
x.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0           // outputs 15
```

I'm wondering why the language has been built to accommodate this. Any known (or outworldly) use case?

Comment: `x.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0` What's this?. `X` is not a tuple.

Comment: Yes, x is a "1-tuple"

Comment: Not an answer: But this would make a lot of things easier. In other words, everything is implicitly a vector making the syntax for 1 element vectors nicer to work with.

Comment: Which Xcode version are you using? I know that `x.0` was treated as `(x).0` (compare e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26506919/why-is-it-always-possible-to-access-the-0-element-of-an-optional-tuple-in-swift), but your code does not compile (anymore) with Xcode 7.1.1.

Comment: @MartinR yes, I do have Xcode update pending. So i'm still on Swift 1. Is it that this behaviour has been omitted in Swift 2.x?

Comment: I can confirm that your code compiles in Xcode 6.4 but not in 7.1.1. So it changed in Swift 2.0 or 2.1. However, I could not find that change in the release notes, so Apple "silently" changed it. Compare https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/72211#72211 in the developer forum: *"Single-element tuple is not a tuple. The support a single-element tuple has been disabled in early betas. Are always interpreted as the internal type of the parenthesis.."*

Comment: I should upgrade my development environment soon then. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know can it be the right [answer](https://medium.com/swift-programming/facets-of-swift-part-2-tuples-4bfe58d21abf), but it gives some information and shows that it's a known thing. Look this 2 sections:

> Special: The 1-Tuple
>
> Bonus Track: Tuples All the Way Down